# select distinct rows without special character in the first occurrence in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in mysql table with rows like

```
CT Scan
 CT Scan
CCT Test
CCT Test
 CCT Test
```

As you can see the values are same but the occurrence in some has a space as first character.

I would like to select the distinct records from that table, which will eventually be like

```
CT Scan 
CCT Test
```

Currently running the distinct query gives me all the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct trim(col) from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct trim(column_name) from your_table
```

trim(column_name) removes leading or trailing spaces and returns the value.